# Mosquitto Broker Debug

Tags: debugging, mqtt, mosquitto

I want debug the mosquitto broker in mac os, to show how functions are applied to understand the underlying technique in mosquitto.

I have loaded it into eclipse c version but can't build it and how the debugging approach ist best suited for?

I want start a mqtt client with paho and then trace the function calls to the broker.

Comment: First better focus why it cant be built. What are the build errors?

Comment: the complete steps cmake . outputs it is configured then with make it stops at 32% with the following output Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_CTX_set_psk_client_callback", referenced from:
      __mosquitto_socket_connect in net_mosq.c.o
  "_TLSv1_1_client_method", referenced from:
  ...
make[2]: *** [lib/libmosquitto.1.4.7.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
____________________________________

Comment: do you have openssl installed?

Comment: Happens to me too ....... :(